# Workarounds for aes_gcm_siv 32-byte key requirement?

Tags: rust, aes-gcm

Using any password that isn't 32 bytes makes the program panic with:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `4`,
 right: `32`'
```

The easy solution seems to be either filling it out with zeros or trimming the password from 0 to 31, but why? I doubt it has any security implications since it won't let you use more than 32 bytes. Is there a workaround other than the aforementioned easy solution to allow users to have longer passwords other than rewriting the crate?

The following is a snippet of my code for context:

```
use aes_gcm_siv::Aes256GcmSiv;
use aes_gcm_siv::aead::{Aead, NewAead, generic_array::GenericArray};

fn encrypt_file(pass: &str, file: &str) {
    println!("{}", pass);
    let key = GenericArray::from_slice(pass.as_bytes());
    let cipher = Aes256GcmSiv::new(&key);
    //...
}
```

I dislike the given usage examples from https://docs.rs/aes-gcm-siv/0.9.0/aes_gcm_siv/. Using a 32 character long hard-coded key seems pretty deceiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you're using a password directly as a key.  You don't want to do that.  AES requires a 128-bit, 192-bit, or 256-bit key, and ideally you want it to be indistinguishable from random, which a password typically is not.

If you have a low-entropy secret, you'll probably want to use something like Argon2id to take that passphrase and a random salt of sufficient length to derive a key.  If you have a strong secret with lots of entropy, then you can use something like HKDF to generate a key.  If you do either of those things, you can generate a key that's exactly 32 bytes long, and, if you want to, a random nonce for the encryption as well.  Since you're using AES-GCM-SIV, you can also use a random nonce and just derive the key this way.

Comment: Awesome! My problem was thinking that the key was the same as the password due to the given example on the cargo doc.